# Is there a specialized literate programming web-file editor that supports navigating in a Knuth's web file e.g. "tex.web"?

Tags: tex-core, literate-programming, web, cweb

What do I mean by that?

- displaying starred and unstarred sections of cursor position
- displaying title of starred section
- displaying `See also sections` if exists
- displaying `This code is used in section` if exists
- jumping by clicking a section
- jumping navigate back
- displaying (estimated) pagenumber of cursor position according to pdf view

I think now you know what I mean.

Comment: I've never heard of one. We should ask Paulo do make it :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Paulo Cereda?

Comment: The second part of my comment was meant as a joke :-) But yes, that's our guy!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm sure Paulo will finish it right after his catcode aware syntax highlighter ;)

Comment: @TeXnician There will be no more editor wars after that ;-)

Comment: I'm working on something like that (and a few more features), except for displaying the program on a webpage instead. I think the web is a natural setting for WEB. Have something barebones so far (achieved in a hacky way by parsing the output of weave) but it needs a rewrite to be done “properly” and will be ready in a few more weeks hopefully. But in the meantime if something like this already exists or if someone else writes one, it will save me a lot of effort. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Did you ever finish your program?

Comment: @DonHosek No I didn't, unfortunately. :-( I'm still interested though, and coincidentally I just now noticed that just yesterday on chat, another user texdr.aft [also seems interested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58289859#58289859) — anyone working on this should join forces and hopefully something will get done.

Comment: @DonHosek I invited you (and the other user) to https://github.com/shreevatsa/webWEB/discussions/1 (will make it public after everyone mentioned has taken a look and no one objects) — I imagine it may even be a not-very-difficult job for anyone with experience writing parsers, compilers, etc, but I'm not one of them. :-)